# Android UI test unable to resolve activity for: Intent

Tags: android, testing, junit, kotlin, android-espresso

I have an activity that requires an intent to start. I am trying to run a UI instrument test that initializes the intent before starting the activity but my test fails with the following java.lang.RuntimeException.

What am I doing wrong? I found an example [here](https://github.com/pawegio/BlackCat/blob/master/app/src/androidTest/kotlin/com/pawegio/blackcat/ui/activity/UserDetailsActivityTest.kt) but I can't spot any differences...

Thanks!

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not launch activity
at android.support.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.startActivitySync(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:460)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule.launchActivity(ActivityTestRule.java:354)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:525)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:101)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:384)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2074)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve activity for: Intent { flg=0x14000000 cmp=com.afitzwa.viewmodeltestingapp.test/com.afitzwa.viewmodeltestingapp.MainActivity (has extras) }
at android.app.Instrumentation.startActivitySync(Instrumentation.java:439)
at android.support.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.access$101(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:96)
at android.support.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation$4.call(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:436)
at android.support.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation$4.call(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:433)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

ExampleInstrumentedTest.kt

```
package com.afitzwa.viewmodeltestingapp

import android.content.Intent
import android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry
import android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4

import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

import org.junit.Assert.*
import org.junit.Rule

/**
 * Instrumented test, which will execute on an Android device.
 *
 * See [testing documentation](http://d.android.com/tools/testing).
 */
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class ExampleInstrumentedTest {

    @Rule
    @JvmField
    val activityRule = object : ActivityTestRule<MainActivity>(MainActivity::class.java) {
        override fun getActivityIntent(): Intent {
            return Intent(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().context, MainActivity::class.java)
                .apply {
                    putExtra("TEST", "TEST")
                }
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun useAppContext() {
        // Context of the app under test.
        val appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()
        assertEquals("com.afitzwa.viewmodeltestingapp", appContext.packageName)
    }
}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.afitzwa.viewmodeltestingapp

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.afitzwa.viewmodeltestingapp.ui.main.MainFragment

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, MainFragment.newInstance())
                .commitNow()
        }
        val data = intent.getStringExtra(TEST_EXTRA)
    }

    companion object {
        val TEST_EXTRA = "foo"
    }
}
```

build.gradle (app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.afitzwa.viewmodeltestingapp"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The example you linked to uses `InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext`, you used `InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().context`

The reason these are not equivalent is because android does not allow you to directly launch activities from an external context. The `targetContext` property is configured to be a part of the application and does not trigger these constraints, but the Instrumentation's `context` is not considered a part of the application, so it cannot resolve the activity.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use next code for `activityRule`:

```
@Rule
@JvmField
val activityRule = object : ActivityTestRule<MainActivity>(MainActivity::class.java) {
    override fun getActivityIntent(): Intent {
        return Intent(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext(), MainActivity::class.java)
            .apply {
                putExtra("TEST", "TEST")
            }
    }
}
```

Instead of `InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().context` write `InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()`.